# Hide Div on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Div that shows up on button click and then lies over some other content, where the button to show the content lies too. I want to hide this div again by scrolling. I have some code which works, but only with limitations which makes it unusable.

I tried the following code:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.hidden-content').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

This actually works but here is the problem: The button I use to show the content does not work anymore while hover-animations in this div still works everywhere. So I do not think this is a problem about a hidden div with a high z-Index value what lies above of everything.

I also tried the following code based on some help of the user Ned Hulton for hiding this div on a button click which worked perfectly fine, but I didn't get the translation for the scroll event right as it seems.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.hidden-content').animate({"opacity":"0"}, function(){
        $(this).css({"zIndex":"-1"})
});
});
```

And maybe it will also help if I show you the code to make the div appear by a click on a button:

```
$('.clickable-content').click(function(e) {
      $('.hidden-content').css({
        "opacity":"1",
        "z-index": "9"
        });
    });
```

Hope someone can help me out! Thak you for reading!

Comment: Post a link to codepen.io or similar.  fadeOut() adds a css property of display:none after the animation is complete. I avoid using it for that reason.

Comment: This actually just solved my problem. I took a free course about javascript where fadeout () was explained as turning the opacity slowly from 1 zu 0, giving it this fading animation. What was not explained was the display:none property. I always wandered why the faded element would not sit on top of everything else if only the opacity would be changed but didn't figured it out. So I just added a display:block; property to my click() event and gave the opacity an animation so there will also this smooth transition of fading in when the content appears. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: No problem, please like my comment

Comment: I would love to show my appreciation through upvoting your comment, but it seems like I need at least 15 Reputation for this and I currently have only 3.